# Error Opening Connection to MS Access DB in VB.NET WEB APPLICATION when uploaded to server using ADO ODBC

Tags: windows, vb.net, ms-access, web-applications, adodb

I have a new application uploaded to Windows server that is attempting to read MS Access DB and I get the error:

ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tracing shows that I get the error at the point where I try to open the connection.

This is my first WEB APPLICATION in Visual Studio 2019. I have other VS WEBSITE applications that also read DBs in the same way. Those work simply by referencing ADODB.DLL and then placing the ADODB.DLL file in the BIN folder of the published website.

I verified that the DB is good with all the proper permissions and connection strings by opening/reading the same database in my one of my website applications. No problem. Both my WEBSITE apps and my WEB APPLICATION read the database with the same exact class module attached to the project.

So the only difference appears to be that one is a WEB APPLICATION (with compiled code-behind) and the other is a WEBSITE (with uncompiled code behind). But again, the database is opened in an identical class modules attached to the projects.

I noticed that the PUBLISH feature in VS seems to ignore the ADODB.DLL file in my bin folder (ie does not publish it to the server even though it is referenced). But even if I manually upload the DLL to the BIN folder of the server, I get the error.

My server support says that I need to add a System.DSN to access the database. I tried that (may have done it incorrectly), but it didn't work. And seems wrong given that I read databases the same way in my website apps.

So it "feels like" the published web app DLLs cannot find the ADODB.DLL when it is accessed in a web application. Should I be putting it in a different location or publishing differently somehow?

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ok, so the site works local.

There are two issues you have to deal with. First up, there is a good possible that the web site is running as x64 bits. As a result, that web site needs to have the x64 bit version of the Access database engine installed (ACE).

In other words that target web site needs to have support for Access installed, and these days MOST web sites by default run as x64 bits

And I believe that you need MORE then just the ADO .dll installed. If you use a mdb file, then the chances are rather high that JET x32 is installed. But if the web server is x64 bits, then you need to install x64 bit ACE on that server. This one:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Make sure from above that you choose the correct x64 bit one, or you may be able to force the web site to run as x32 bits - but that's often a issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Feel free to ignore this until I try to implement your answer. but I am confused. As I said, I have older apps (also working on my local machine) that are VS WEBSITES (as opposed to the current compiled WEB APPL (a VS distinction only?). But these older websites DO successfully access databases on the server (including, by experiment, the one for my new application). I update those regularly in VS on my same local machine and they continue to work. Does the fact that it is a WEB APP in VS make my application 64bit? I can't see anything in the project that tells me.

Comment: As default web VS site runs as x32. In past mdb would work since access database engine has been installed by default on every copy of windows since BEOFRE windows XP. So to open access mdb files you never had to install anything. If you use a accDB file, then you need to have the ACE data engine installed (NOT installed by default). So on your local machine, then using a mdb access file would work without installing JET for mdb files. But if you publish to a web server then you are likely running as x64. There is no x64 bit version of JET, but there is one for ACE. But ACE must be installed

Comment: As for project settings? Well, we have to first determine if you usiing a mdb file, or a accDB file. And of course there are settings. You have ANY CPU, or x64 or x86. during development ANY will result in a x32 process since VS is actualy only a x32 bit applicaiton. You can force the project to x64 or x32 by changing the ANY cpu to x32/x64.  So if you are using a mdb file, and force your project to x64 - you find it don't work anymore until such time you installed the x64 bit version of ACE. ACE can open mdb or accDB files - but the pre-installed jet data engine can only open mdb as x32 bits

Comment: Thanks again. I'm having our leased server admin install ACE. Also, I noticed an inconsistency with the targeted asp version. Only 4.0 and below are currently on my server. VS defaulted to 4.7.2, I changed the web-config so that it would run, but failed to change the project to use 4.0. I don't know if that caused any problems but they're going to install 4.7.2 also. I'll leave this question open until I determine that these changes worked.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks for the help. My server administrator installed 64bit ACE engine and the app is now working.